# Django Postgres Indexing related model's property

Tags: django, postgresql

If I have 1M records called `Tickets` that all have a related foreign key called `Status` and I am ordering those 1M records by the `status__name`, does a separate index need to be created or is it using the index for foreign keys (i.e. status_id) that was created?  I understand that if I was ordering the pks, the index could be used, but don't understand the internals enough to understand what it would do in this case (I don't have this many records yet to run `EXPLAIN` on fyi).  Thanks for the help/explanation!

Comment: If you order by name then you need to have an index on name, index on id won't help here. Here is an extra tip - you don't need a separated status table most likely. What do you have there, id and name? Just use that name as a value and save yourself headaches in the future with performance and query complexity.

Comment: @serg Yep that is great tip! Probably go that route. Then just for learning purposes, if I have a FK on ticket called location and am sorting tickets by location name, would I have to index ticket's location name through ticket (an index of ticket's sorted by location name) or is an index on location name all that is needed?  A bit unfamiliar with how this type of related lookup will work.

Comment: Index is applied to current table fields only, don't think you can index ticket.location.name, so would need to go to location table and create an index or name there, and it will be used when sorting by ticket.location.name.